# C++ Add A Bitmap from resource to Picture Control

Tags: c++, bitmap, picturebox

i want to display a bitmap on my Picture control,
but actually no matter what Im trying, it doesnt work.
Right now my method looks like this:

```
SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd ,picture_CTRL, BM_SETIMAGE , IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM) MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));
```

I have also already tried to use the

```
STM_SETIMAGE
```

Message, but it wont work as well.
My Picture Control property "Type" is set to "Bitmap" and my Bitmap has an ID in resource.h

Hope you guys can help :)

Answer (score 3):

First, you can't just mix and match messages in standard Windows controls. `BM_SETIMAGE` and `STM_SETIMAGE` have completely different values. If you are using a Static control, use `STM_SETIMAGE`. If you are using a Button control, use `BM_SETIMAGE`.

Second, the [documentation for `STM_SETIMAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760782%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that the `LPARAM` must be a handle to the image. You are passing a resource ID. You need to get the handle by calling `LoadImage` first. For example:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = reinterpret_cast<HBITMAP>(LoadImage(
    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1),
    IMAGE_BITMAP,
    0,
    0,
    0));

SendDlgItemMessage(
    hWnd,
    picture_CTRL,
    STM_SETIMAGE,
    IMAGE_BITMAP,
    reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(hBitmap));
```

Note that according to the documentation you are responsible for deleting the bitmap when you are done with it.

EDITS: Note that I had two problems in my original version of the code, both caused by copying and pasting from the question. I failed to pass the handle as the `LPARAM` myself and I used `BM_SETIMAGE` instead of `STM_SETIMAGE`. I will also add a note in the answer that, as Cody Gray pointed out, the MSDN documentation for a function or message will tell you whether you can use `MAKEINTRESOURCE`.

Comment: +1 Good summary of the problems. It's worth pointing out that in the cases where you can use the `MAKEINTRESOURCE` macro, this will be noted clearly in the documentation.